# Int and Integer in Twitter API

Tags: twitter, tweepy, tweets, twython

In Twitter API (https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/tweet-object), some of the fields are Int and some others Integer which are Nullable. For instance `retweet_count` is Int, but `favourite_count` is Integer (which is Nullable). What does it mean for `favourite_count` to be Nullable? and why `favourite_count` can be Nullable but `retweet_count` cannot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked a [similar question](https://twittercommunity.com/t/meaning-of-null-favorite-count/10884) a few years back on the Twitter forum.

For scalability, the Twitter API has eventual consistency. The effect is that sometimes you won't receive all of the data or the data hasn't been updated.

Because of this, some fields are marked as `nullable` to indicate that there may or may not be data for that field, but we don't know at the time of the query.